# Suitables TERM variable values for a serial console

Tags: linux, console, serial-port, serial-console

To enable a serial console on Linux, one uses `getty` (most usually, its variant `agetty`). This binary takes as argument, among other, the value to initialize the **TERM** variable with.

On Debian, with Sys V init, the default was **vt100**. With systemd, the default used to be **vt102**, and nowadays it's **vt220**.

After playing a bit with QEMU virtual machines and `virt-viewer`, as well as `virsh console` command, I noticed some things:

- With **vt100**, `ls --color` displays colors, but `vim`'s syntax highlighting doesn't work
- with **vt102** or **vt220**, neither of them displays colors
- Only with **TERM** variable set to **linux**, do both `ls` and `vim` use colors

So I guess that independently of the actual "color support", each application looks at the **TERM** variable and acts accordingly, which would explain the differences noted above.

After reading the [Serial Console HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO), I understand that the value of the **TERM** variable should depend on the actual model of physical terminal which would be connected to the serial port, according to its capabilities.

Note that, according to [Lennart Poettering's blog](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html), **TERM** should be set to **linux** only with real virtual terminals (as opposed to serial ones). On the other hand, [Arch Linux' Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/working_with_the_serial_console) doesn't seem to mind (see the `/etc/inittab` lines it proposes).

So my questions are:

In a general case, what happens if the **TERM** variable is set to **linux** on a console connected to a less-capable terminal, like a DEC VT100, VT102 or VT220, or some RS-232 software terminal emulators like `minicom` or `termite` ?

More realistically (in my particular case), is it OK to set the **TERM** variable to **linux** in a "virtual" serial console on a QEMU VM, to which I will connect through `virt-viewer` or `virsh console` ?

Comment: "real virtual" is a somewhat odd turn of phrase, and it is arguable that a DEC VT is "less capable" than the Linux built-in terminal emulator.  (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TERM` setting tells the application program what capabilities the terminal it is communicating with has, and how to utilize these capabilities (typically via a library like ncurses). In plain English: it tells what control sequences (escape sequences) it should send to move the cursor arount the screen, to change the text color, how to erase a region of the screen, what sequences the function keys transmit, etc. Some of these capabilities may be missing, like color support.

Most of the terminal types in use today are somehow related to the "grand daddy" of "glass ttys", the DEC VT100. This is why terminal types are **mostly** interchangeable, so setting the wrong type typcally results in a mostly working setup, but with some glitches.

So, to answer the questions "which should I use" and "what happens if I use the wrong setting"? Some control sequences may be mismatched, i.e. the program sends cursor movement sequences that differ from the ones the terminal emulator expects. Or color support is missing. (Btw. the original VT100 did definitely not support color...) The correct setting should be provided by the terminal emulator documentation, but there is no harm in experimenting to see which setting works the best. It's OK to use "linux" if it works for you.

Comment: The Linux built-in terminal emulator famously swaps the DECFNK sequences for Home and End with those for Find and Select, for example.